# MySQL .sql Import Schedule

Tags: php, mysql, database, command-line

To start with, This is the first time I've really used MySQL like this so I'm not familiar with everything.

I am trying to import a .sql file on a schedule into MySQL.

Some Background

The file comes from a remote server and is downloaded to c:\mysql dump\backup.sql

OS is 2012 R2
MySQL is 5.6

I have tried to get it running manual before trying to make a script.

this is what i've been typing in but i just keep getting a syntax error.

```
-u username -p database_name < 'c:\mysql dump\backup.sql'
```

If i do a manual import through phpmyadmin it works so there is no problem with the sql file.

I have now run out of ideas on why this isnt working.

Answer (score 0):

If each query in the backup.sql on a single line this works:

```
$fp = fopen('c:\mysql dump\backup.sql','r')
while (($text= fgets($fp , 4096)) !== false) {
  $sql = $text;
  mysqli_query($link,$sql);
  if(mysqli_errno() > 0){$err += 1; $errors[] = mysqli_error ($link);}
  if(mysqli_affected_rows($link ) > 0){$updates += 1;}
}
```